# Can't get the values when compare two columns in sql

Tags: sql

I need help with this query

```
select ca_city from AM_PROVISIONAL where ca_province='پنجاب'  group by ca_city
```

when I run it, it shows the blank field but the database exists.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074562/group-by-without-aggregate-function to understand how GROUP BY works

Comment: Are you sure your `AM_PROVISIONAL` table supports your character set? What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE AM_PROVISIONAL` print?

Comment: (1) Make sure your DB support the UTF8 character set  (2) also provide some data of the ca_city and ca_province columns from the table

Comment: sorry to all i just forget to write 'N' as it support and used for multilanguage. if we compare two different languages we have to use this.