# The GROUP BY clause must be used with aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, aggregate-functions

GROUP BY clause  need an aggregate ?

Comment: What would be the point without aggregate functions.

Comment: No.

Check this posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074562/group-by-without-aggregate-function

Answer (score 3):

No, an aggregate query doesn't need a `GROUP BY` clause. But if no such clause is present the query only generates a single result row, aggregating the entire table.

It's sort of like there was an implicit `GROUP BY 'nothing'` clause inserted by the DBMS if you don't provide your own.