# How To Find Duplicate Of Single Word (Not Value) In A Column

Tags: sql-server

I want to find duplicate of single word in my ItemDescription column. Please Look The Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBX7F.jpg .Not the duplicate value but the duplicate of single word with in the value. Is it Possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE` operator to find occurrences of your words and operator `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find duplicates:

```
SELECT 
i.ItemDescription 
FROM dbo.tbiitems i
WHERE i.ItemDescription LIKE '%NR%' OR i.ItemDescription LIKE '%NRCONDITIONER%' OR 
i.ItemDescription LIKE '%CREAMBATH%'
GROUP BY i.ItemDescription
HAVING COUNT(i.ItemDescription) > 1
```

or if you want to find counts of `ItemDescription` and follow **the SQL rules** [this subject on SO for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074562/group-by-without-aggregate-function) (thanks to @Daniel E.):

```
SELECT 
i.ItemDescription, COUNT(i.ItemDescription) AS CountItemDescription
FROM dbo.tbiitems i
WHERE i.ItemDescription LIKE '%NR%' OR i.ItemDescription LIKE '%NRCONDITIONER%' OR 
i.ItemDescription LIKE '%CREAMBATH%'
GROUP BY i.ItemDescription
HAVING COUNT(i.ItemDescription) > 1
```

Comment: @DanielE. thanks for your comment, but I've used `GROUP BY i.ItemDescription`

Comment: @DanielE. Thanks! I've added your comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks all, you guys really good in helping person in need :D