# SQL - I am trying to isolate or group each transaction by each cardholder and my code is below

Tags: sql

The code runs ok when i don't have the last line (GROUP BY ch.name).  When I include the line I receive an error listed below - I am trying to get a query where I can identify and group many things such as grouping transactions by cardholder and grouping from 7:00 - 9:00 AM EST.  Still new to coding so a bit frustrated.  Any help is appreciated!

> ERROR: column "t.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>
> LINE 1: SELECT ch.name, t.date, t.amount, t.card AS "Credit Card", t...
>                              ^
>   SQL state: 42803
>   Character: 17

My query:

```
SELECT 
    ch.name, t.date, t.amount, t.card AS "Credit Card", t.id_merchant,
    m.name AS "Merchan, mc.name AS "merchant category"
FROM
    transaction AS t
JOIN 
    credit_card AS cc ON (t.card = cc.card)
JOIN 
    card_holder AS ch ON (cc.cardholder_id = ch.id)
JOIN 
    merchant AS m ON (t.id_merchant = m.id)
JOIN 
    merchant_category AS mc ON (m.id_merchant_category = mc.id)
GROUP BY 
    ch.name;
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images). Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: You typically combine GROUP BY with set functions, to calculate values per group.

Comment: Perhaps you want `ORDER BY ch.name;` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ch.name, t.date, t.amount, t.card AS "Credit Card", t.id_merchant, m.name AS "Merchan mc.name AS "merchant category" 
FROM transaction AS t 
JOIN credit_card AS cc ON (t.card = cc.card) 
JOIN card_holder AS ch ON (cc.cardholder_id = ch.id) 
JOIN merchant AS m ON (t.id_merchant = m.id) 
JOIN merchant_category AS mc ON (m.id_merchant_category = mc.id) 
GROUP BY (ch.name, t.date, t.amount, t.card, t.id_merchant, m.name, mc.name);
```

Try above.

Comment: You mean SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: This answer makes no sense, why would you GROUP BY all the fields in the SELECT?

Comment: You need to specify all the columns in group by clause.

Comment: It makes sense only if you have aggregation, which is not the case here

Comment: group by is aggregate function. that's why you need to specify all the column in group by clause.

Comment: You are using group by, so this whole result set will be aggregate.

Comment: @jarlh Group by without aggregate is basically the same as distinct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074562/group-by-without-aggregate-function however for readability distinct is the preferred method.

Comment: @DanDonoghue, you can also do `SELECT ... UNION same SELECT`, to get distinct result. But I still do SELECT DISTINCT... (Sarcasm)